# TYPO3 smooth migration causes fatal error

Tags: php, typo3, upgrade

I have TYPO3 version **4.7.3-dev**.
I want to upgrade to version **6.2 LTS** and I found a migration checking tool **Smooth migration**.
When I want to show the results I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getResultAnalyzer() on a non-object in \typo3conf\ext\smoothmigration\Classes\ViewHelpers\ResultAnalyzerViewHelper.php on line 47
```

Is there any other way to show the results except searching in database?

Comment: non-object means something probably failed, return false/0/whatever and the next bits of code blindly assumed nothing could fail and try to use that false/0/whatever as if it was an object.

Comment: I know what the error means. But I do not know the solution to fix it. I even know why it fails. But it still does not help me to solve that. I copied the fatal error so it could be found easily on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm i think you should take another way. Its easier to link the new Typo3 Sources and go to the installation Tool. There you have the upgrade Wizard. During the Update you get a lot of informations how to check extensions and make the upgrade to 6.2.

Most times its easier to get that way. The installer will first check all your extensions and disable unsupported and incompatible extensions. After that he check the complete folder structure and after all checks the upgrade starts.

Comment: To link the new Sources means to override /typo3 folder with the new version?

Comment: I tried that but it failed. I will try one more time. The smooth migration worked also on 2nd attempt.

Comment: I got so many fatal errors trying upgrade with installation tool. I had to turn off all the extensions and I have to install passwordsalt extension. I hope it will be all.

Answer (score 0):

The Smooth Migration extension and the Install Tool don't cover the same areas of a migration.  The Smooth Migration gives you hints about code in extensions that will fail in new TYPO3 versions, e.g. require statements to TYPO3 core files that have a new location, Fluid ViewHelpers that were removed and functions that were deprecated or removed. This helps you to fix the code of your extensions. This is especially useful if you have custom extensions or old extensions that are not maintained anymore and helps you to upgrade on your own. If EXT:smoothmigration doesn't work, clear all the caches (also typo3temp/Cache) and try again.

The Install Tool guides your through the core updating process. I suggest to disable all non-core extensions (in PackageStates.php --> set active to inactive after this file has been generated) so you can first have the core functions running again. Then, re-install and upgrade if necessary the extensions piece by piece and get all the functionality back.

Comment: I tried this and the installation failed on missing saltedpasswords extension.